# Java Webcrawler that searches for keyword

Tags: java, web, web-crawler

I'm trying to have a web crawler return true when it finds a given word on a webpage. The return true statement never runs though so I can't use it properly. Anyone have a simply way to do this? Thanks

```
    public static boolean keywordSearch(String url, String keyword){
    String strTemp = "";
    try {
        URL my_url = new URL(url);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream()));
        while(null != (strTemp = br.readLine())){
            if (strTemp.contains(keyword)){
                return true;
            }
    }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your method works for me. It returns `true` for searching the URL of this question for the word "keyword". Why do you think it is not working, and can you give an example URL and keyword where it should work but doesn't?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First read in the contents of the URL using a method like the following:

```
public static String getText(String url) throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                    connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        response.append(inputLine);

    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Then check if the contents of the URL contains the keyword like so:

```
String content = URLConnectionReader.getText("http://www.someurl.com/page.html");
if(content.contains("someKeyword"))
{
    // content of url contains keyword
}
```

Comment: Why fill memory with the entire contents of the page? What if it's several gigabytes?

Comment: perfect, Thanks you! I see what would happen if it is a very large page, however it works for my needs. Can you share how you would go about doing this?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I cannot imagine the source of a webpage would ever be gigabytes. The source of a webpage is usually in KB and is typically under 1 MB.

Comment: @DallasSeroski You could change the getText() function to keywordSearch() and have it also accept a keyword string parameter. Change the while loop to this: `while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
response.append(inputLine); if(response.contains(keyword)) in.close(); return true; }` and then change `return response.toString();` to `return false;`

Comment: You are not taking any percautions to make sure that your input is actually a `text/html` page, or that it doesn't exceed a certain size. Beyond this, it is completely redundant to load the data to memory even if it is just 1k. You are not saving reads and you are not achieving anything that was not in the original program.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think those precautions as well as many others are outside the scope of this problem though as the user simply asked how to check if the contents of a URL contain a keyword.